# How to add an element in a table that contains multiple instances of objects from another table in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, relational-database

I'm sure there is a simple solution to my problem but I'm having trouble finding it online so I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

So I have a Spring Boot application that uses an external database. I have a table and class called Ingredient that contains the various ingredients. That class has all the necessary methods (PUT, POST, DELETE, GET) and they work as intended.

Now I need to implement another class called Food and every object of type Food should be initiated with a name and a list of Ingredients.

I don't know how to implement it. I made the class Food and I defined a @ManyToMany relationship between the two classes/tables but I don't know how to implement the POST method for the Food.

I tried googling but I'm having trouble wording my problem.

Comment: Your question is confusing. It's not clear if you are having a problem with your ORM mapping (to answer that, please provide the name of the framework) or if you can't configure the @RequestMapping in your controller to expose a new endpoint. Please provide more info

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Neuquino hello and thank you for commenting. 
My problem is both. I'm using Spring Boot with Flyway and Postgres.
The database is in a Docker container and I have a docker-compose file that starts the container and the database in it.
I made a .sql file to create the tables in the database. 
I made the "Ingredient", IngredientController", "IngredientService" and "IngredientRepository" classes to implement the POST, GET, PUT and DELETE methods so I can add/get/delete/modify ingredients in the database.

Comment: @Neuquino
Now I'm implementing a second object, Food, that also has to be stored in the database. 
The complication with this is that a "Food" contains one or more "Ingredients" and I am not sure how to implement that. 
I searched online but only found tutorials and videos that show how to create a ManyToMany relationship and after adding a Food to the table add Ingredients to it with a PutMapping. 
What I would like to do is to save in the database a "Food" object with a PostMapping passing it a name (String) and a List<Ingredient>

Comment: I created the Food, FoodController, FoodService and FoodRepository classes and implemented the solutions found online (create a Food object and the add Ingredients to it one by one with Put methods). 

But now I have another problem. In all these tutorials and videos the creators don't use Flyway and Hibernate creates the tables for them so it all works perfectly but I create my  own tables with hibernate and the ManyToMany relationship and the JoinTable is now creating new problems.